# Перенести ТОЛЬКО измнения одного комита,из одной ветки в другу

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Можно ли перенести изменения из одной ветки в другую, без конфликта.

Хочу сделать такое, у меня есть 2 платы (2 ветки), на которых могу отлаживать алгоритмы, отличаются платы только файлом инициализации (или комитом инициализации, может быть несколько файлов)

После добавления изменений в одной ветки, хочу перекинуть только внесенные изменения в другую ветку. Команда  `cherry-pick`, делает такое с конфликтом, так как есть изменения в файлах инициализации.

---

Хорошо, опишу чуть подробнее,я занимаюсь embedded программированием и использую git чисто для себя, что бы
создавать тестовые ветки всякой разной периферии, и не терять(портить) основной проект.

Так вот по поводу плат вы правильно поняли это печатные плат, с подключением всякой периферии к процессору
и вот как раз подключение чуть чуть отличается,но есть алгоритмы которые совсем не зависят от железа вот их я и хочу гонять, то на одной плате то на другой плате,
и хочу что бы все изменения которые внес, на одной плате можно было не включая голову перенести на другую, и там продолжить.

Моя программа имеет модульный (`.с`, `.h` файлы) состав, инициализация каждой периферии, находится в своем модуле, что бы можно было
кинуть два файла в другой(новый), проект и не искать как же его потом включить. (Но тут уже да рассматриваю вариант, вынести все функции инициализации в отдельный файл).

Но в данном варианте, такое не подходит по тому что, помимо файлов инициализации, под каждую плату пришлось вносить некоторые мелкие изменения в несколько модулей, (из за отличия размера flash в процессора, изменился размер страницы, и на одно плате в функции передачи данных изменил способ передачи без использования DMA)
хоть это как то и можно вынести, в файл конфигурации, но всё равно что нибудь новое может вылезти ещё, типа как с изменением способа передачи.

Комментарий player one, навел меня на мысль, сделать для каждого модуля свою репозиторию, и в новом проекте их все объединять с помощью submdule, не знаю к чему это приведет, ещё сильно не копал в этом направлении.

Но думаю должно получится так, что если нашёл какой то баг в одном модуле, то он автоматически, устранится в новых проектах
а старые не заденутся если специально не скачивать модуль, и вносить эти изменения, это меня вполне устраивает,я уже такое давно хотел сделать но не знал в какую сторону копать.

Comment: а вы открывали файл, который приводит к конфликту? Если я не ошибаюсь, в конфликтные файлы добавляются все содержимое из сливаемых веток. Примерно вот так:  `<<<<<<< *HASHofFIRSTCOMMIT*:mergetest
 This is my third line
 =======
 This is a fourth line I am adding
 >>>>>>> *HASHofSECONDCOMMIT*:mergetest`

Comment: Да открывал, там в прицепе  не сложно, всё подправить, но я планирую туда суда прыгать между ветками, и каждый раз не хотелось бы

<<<<<<< HEAD
1)Основная ветка
=======
1)Изменил конфигурацию по данную плату   


2) внес изменения -> этот кусок надо перенести в основную программу 
>>>>>>> 3a796a6... РљРѕРјРёС‚ СЃ РёР·РјРµРЅРµРЅРёСЏРјРё

Comment: Когда вы попытались применить изменения одного коммита в другую ветку, git находится в "подвешенном состоянии" и остановился на конфликтном файле. Как только вы разрешите все конфликты и ПРОДОЛЖИТЕ слияние , Вам не нужно будет править каждый раз файл при переключения на разные коммиты или ветки) Если я не прав, просьба поправить меня. P.S. вызовите команду `git status` чтобы получше понять что гит от Вас хочет.

Comment: Вы ищете не в той стороне. ИМХО решение проблемы надо искать в правильной организации репозитория и рабочего процесса. Конфигурационные файлы специфичные для окружения не должны лежать в репозитории. Если у вас такая ситуация, то уберите конфиги из контроля версий и проблема исчезнет. Если под "файлом инициализации" вы имеете в виду какой-то компилируемый код, то тогда можно подумать в сторону какого-нибудь разделения проекта на модули. Например два отдельных репозитория специфичных для каждой платы, и один репозиторий с общим кодом, который подключен к первым двум через git submdule.

Comment: Благодарю, всех за помощь походу мне надо был git submdule буду разбираться как его использовать.

Comment: @Максим перенёс ваши дополнения из ответа в вопрос. Расскажите, к чему вы в итоге пришли, что получилось?

Answer (score 3):

Я полностью согласен с комментарием player one: вы задаёте какой-то технический вопрос, но возникает он из-за неправильной организации рабочего процесса. И правильно будет рекомендовать вам навести порядок в рабочем процессе, а не пояснять, как разрубить гордиев узел с конкретным техническим вопросом.

Судя по вашему описанию, у вас в проекте две ветки, практически полностью идентичные. Вы дублируете очень большое число файлов, помимо одного файла конфигурации и возможно нескольких ещё файлов. И вы постоянно переключаетесь с ветки на ветку, "прыгаете".

Вам не кажется, что у вас по сути ДВА проекта, а не ОДИН? И вам нужно два репозитория, один проект = один репозиторий?

Тут же всплывает проблема дублирования: это будут два настолько одинаковых репозитория, что настоятельно нужно вспомнить принцип DRY (Don't repeat yourself) и рекомендовать подумать над тем, чтобы убрать ненужные дубликаты.

Не зная деталей проекта сложно что-то конкретное рекомендовать. Я бы предложил вынести общую часть в 'core' ("движок") и подключать его к своим двум проектам (получается три репозитория: корневой, с общей частью и два мелких репозитория с отличающимися частями). Не знаю, насколько это подходит к вашему проекту, у меня вообще слово "плата" вызывает ассоциацию с печатными платами, не представляю, как их хранят в гит.

А вот насчёт конфигурационного файла тут тоже весьма настоятельно рекомендую задуматься о том, чтобы вынести эти файлы за рамки версионного контроля через механизм `.gitignore`.

Так по крайней мере принято именно в качестве удобного процесса совместной работы нескольких людей (каждый может сделать свои настройки и в гит они не попадут, не будут конфликтовать друг с другом), на разных окружениях (development - stage - production).

Comment: это зависит от того какие именно конфигурации. Если второй разработчик плат нуждается в этих же конфигурациях то логичнее их хранить в гит